# access memory crashed when try to initialize 1G memory usin for loop

Tags: c

I am wondering why the following code will crash?

My environment is ubuntu64,gcc 4.8.1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE 1024*1024*1024
int main()
{
    printf("%ld,%ld,%ld\n",sizeof(int),sizeof(long),sizeof(size_t));//output 4,8,8
    printf("%ld\n",SIZE); //output 1073741824

    int *p = (int*)malloc(SIZE);
    if(!p){
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
    }

    memset(p,0,SIZE);    //this works fine

    size_t i=0;   
    for(;i<SIZE;++i){
            p[i] = 10;  //gdb shows when crashed i = 268436476
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating `SIZE` *bytes*, not `SIZE` *ints*. When you try to write to `SIZE` ints in your `for` loop you are therefore writing beyond the end of allocated memory.

Change:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(SIZE);
```

to:

```
int *p = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(p[0]));
```

Note also that the `int` cast which I have removed is both [redundant and potentially harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Why would the cast be potentially harmful?

Comment: See the question I linked to in the answer - the cast can obscure the fact that you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` which could result in a truncated (and therefore invalid) pointer.

Comment: Thanks, Shall we always use calloc instead of malloc to avoid these silly mistake?

Comment: Don't use `calloc` unless you need to initialise the memory to all zeroes.

Comment: OK, maybe always use malloc as "malloc (SIZE * sizeof(unit))" would be safer:)

Comment: when not using `calloc()` you have to make sure that `SIZE * sizeof p[0]` does not overflow. `calloc()` might have no overhead on some platforms (Linux) because underlying memory allocation zeros always the memory due to security considerations.

Comment: Yes, but use `malloc(SIZE * sizeof(p[0]))` as above, not `malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
int *p = calloc(SIZE, sizeof p[0]);
```